# How do I install drivers in Linux?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics

How to install [these Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21938/Graphics-Linux-PowerVR-Graphics-Media-Drivers) drivers?
I've never used Linux before.

Can someone explain it step by step?

**PC specs:**

- Pc model:

  acer aspire one d270 26dws
  CPU:Intel® Atom™ CPU N2600 @ 1.6 GHz x4

**OS Version:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31340/discussion-on-question-by-das-has-how-do-i-install-drivers-in-linux).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems that Intel's drivers do not support your the GPU for your CPU (Atom N2600) [as per this post on OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-1-0-5).

> The installer does not support the Ubuntu Linux low-latency kernel **nor
>   does it provide binary drivers for the Intel GMA 3600** (bundled with
>   Intel’s **Atom N2600** and N2800 chipsets).